# Change both border and fill colors in one place in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis

This seems somewhat basic, but is there a way to set the colors for both fill and stroke of a polygon layer at the same time?  I find myself frequently having to change the colors in multiple places, especially when I am using line fill types. Changing the highest level color changes the fills in subordinate layers, but doesn't affect the stroke.

This dialogue allows you to change fill colors in all subordinate styles
[image]

but doesn't affect the strokes
[image]

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you set the stroke colour using the expression editor ("E" box on right of dropdown):

[image]

Then you can use `@symbol_color` for the stroke colour:

[image]

which ignores the colour in the drop-down, and doesn't render it in the preview top right of the dialog, but does (when applied) give you strokes that match the fill. Even if you change the fill colour. Here's what I get, with large dotted strokes so you can see them:

[image]

Comment: In addition to the @symbol_color function you can use @darker(@symbol_color, 150) and @lighter(@symbol_color, 80) in the Stroke Colour expression to make the border 50% darker or 20% lighter respectively. Adjust the numbers as required.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn’t seem to work with marker symbols. The expression editor shows preview value which looks right, but the markers’ stroke is still drawn with the colour from the drop-down. (Qgis 3.2.0)

Comment: If you want to make the stroke 20% lighter you can use: `@darker(@symbol_color, 80) ` (a little counter intuitive IMHO)

Comment: Can this be used in combination with alpha so that the strokes transparency matches the polygons fill transparency?