# Categorized stroke color of a circle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

Is there a way in QGIS to make circles that have strokes with different colours and the colour is based on the categories in one of my data fields?

Comment: You can, but you'd have to set each stroke color seperatley. the categorized symbology type only changes the fill color.

Comment: You can use the data-defined override and set it to `@symbol_color`, but I'm pretty sure this question has been answered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change both border and fill colors in one place in QGIS 3.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295279/change-both-border-and-fill-colors-in-one-place-in-qgis-3-0)

Comment: @JoshC that wasnt what i was looking for. However, Erik's answer below was exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is no fill, only the outline, then there is a simple solution. It is a bit more complex to have both categorized fill and outlines.

---

1. no fill - only outline

Set the layer style to be `categorized`.

Set the value field, click on the `symbol` (or if clicking on the triangle beside it, then select `configure symbol`)

Change the `simple fill` for a `outline line`, eventually set the outline width. Click the top triangle to go back to the main menu.

Select the color ramp, click classify.

[image]

[image]

---

2. categorized fill and categorized outline

If you want fill colors categorized by fieldA and outline colors categorized by fieldB, then you need `rule based styling`.

Start with the `categorized` style type, use `fieldA` and set a color ramp of your choice.

Then change the style type from `categorized` to `rule based`.

For every rule, right click and select `refine current rules / add categories to rule`.

Follow the procedure described above to categorized the outline color (set value `fieldB`, change the symbol to be `outline line`, set the color ramp, back to main rule)

Repeat for the next rule

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are ways, but they are clumbersome, if you have a lot of categories.

Number 1 is, as suggest by [Dror Bogin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/108903/dror-bogin), just run the classification and then change each stroke colour manually.

Number 2 is using data defined override:

[image]

To the right of almost every setting field in the symbology there's two small stacked rectangles with even smaller triangles attached to them. Hit this button to the right of the stroke colour field, then choose "edit". Adapt and enter the following:

```
CASE
WHEN "category column" = 'category 1' THEN 'red'
WHEN "category column" = 'category 2' THEN 'green'
WHEN "category column" = 'category 3' THEN 'blue'
ELSE 'pink'
END
```

`"category column"` is the column you want to "classify" your data on, `'category 1'` is the value of your first category (if you have numerical values, leave out the `'`). `red` obviously is the colour the stroke should have for this category. You also may use RGB-values or HEX-codes. For more details consult the expression builder window. `ELSE 'pink'` just catches any incorrectly entered or classified values.