# Improving resolution of map using QGIS

Tags: maps, resolution

I am using QGIS.

I have a shapefile of Africa. In that shapefile I divide Africa in cells. After, I graduate all the cells according to one variable (see first picture). I would like to see the entire map with the intention to attach the image to a project. However, due to the size of the continent, when I amplify the map to see all the continent the picture (or the variation of the graduation) is not evident (see second picture). When I go to "New Print Layout" and inserting legends and exporting the image, the same happens.

Is it possible to improve the resolution or to do something to see clear the entire map as the first picture or at least improve the second one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the border stroke from a polygon style?

Comment: I am asking about if it is possible to improve the quality of the image in order to appreciate the variation as in the first picture. In the second one, I cannot see so much.

Comment: By removing the border stroke from the polygon style.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is "removing the border stroke of the polygon style" but if it helps to improve my image, I am open to do it. What I should do?

Comment: Change your symbology.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the issue of removing the border stroke of the polygon and changing the symbology?

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html?highlight=symbology. You can change the stroke-width, or make it transparent/invisible. This is not in the Print-Layout, but in the normal QGIS-Window

Comment: Thank you @Vincé . It helps as well as the answer of J.R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @OgeiD is suggesting is going from this :

[image]

To this (exact same thing but the cell have no border) :

[image]

As you can see, the cell are still discernible as the "no pen" for the stroke style setting leave a gap between cell, if you want a seamless look you could set the stroke to the same color as the fill (and leave the stroke width and fill unchanged). If you want to go this way [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295279/change-both-border-and-fill-colors-in-one-place-in-qgis-3-0) could help.

Other alternative are to reduce the width of the stroke and/or to give the stroke a lighter color to be less prominent, just play with possibility till you find setting combination that suit you.